# Reading 0.0 from file into double Arr?

Tags: c++, arrays, double, ifstream, zero

I'm trying to read a bunch of `0.0` from a file that looks like this:

```
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0

0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0

0.0 0.0 3.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0

0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0

0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

into a double arr using this code:

```
double arr[9] = { 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0 };
int tilechoice = 0, random;

ifstream inchoice("D:\\Code\\C++\\Tic Tac Toe AI\\Choices.txt");
inchoice >> fixed >> setprecision(1);
for (int i = 0; i < 11839; i++)
{
    if (i == *b)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            inchoice >> arr[j];
        }
        break;
    }
    else
        inchoice.ignore(36);
```

(`*b` is the line number of the array with the 3 value)

but when I test the output of the arr of the line with the 3 in it, it shows me this:

```
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 3.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

Where the 3.0 is in the wrong position?

Comment: The input seems fine to me. How exactly are you printing the output?

Comment: Which compiler do you use? Works as expected on latest g++

Comment: I'm guessing you're outputting using `cout` but without `setprecision`.

Comment: It seems you don't have a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For instance, what is `b`--as in `i == *b`? We don't know. Because of things like this, it is hard to answer your question. Could you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58831758/edit) and add one? Also, please include your printing code.

Comment: @acraig5075 yeah the cout wasnt setprecisioned u were right

Comment: @Chipster ok i edited in the necessary info im pretty sure sorry about that!

Comment: In code that you're not showing are you doing any reading from `inchoice` using `<<` before getting to line number `b`? Because if you are then the file pointer will not necessarily be at the beginning of the line, which would lead to your situation.

Comment: @acraig5075 no, i think i just wasnt skipping enough characters with the inchoice.ignore which was cascading the values i guess

Answer (score 1):

Your code could be simplified so as not to need that awkward `inchoice.ignore` at all.

```
ifstream inchoice("D:\\Code\\C++\\Tic Tac Toe AI\\Choices.txt");
std::string line; 

for (int i = 0; std::getline(inchoice, line); ++i)
{
    if (i == *b)
    {
        std::stringstream ss(line);
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            inchoice >> arr[j];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing `inchoice.ignore(36)` to `inchoice.ignore(38)` guess the two extra spaces were necessary?

Comment: With a little restructuring to read line-by-line, (see my answer), `istream::ignore` would not be necessary at all.